# please detect the Visual c++ error

Tags: visual-c++

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    x1=LOWORD(z);
    y1=HIWORD(z);
    d=GetDC (w);
    TextOut(d,x1,y1,"AMITA",6);
    ReleaseDC (w,&d);
    break;

Error:: error C2664: 'ReleaseDC' : cannot convert parameter 2
    from 'struct HDC__ ** ' to 'struct HDC__ *
```

Answer (score 3):

`ReleaseDC (w,&d);` should be `ReleaseDC (w,d);`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ReleaseDC (w,d);
```

instead.

It's because [`GetDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871%28VS.85%29.aspx) returns an `HDC` and [`ReleaseDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162920%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is expecting an `HDC` as well, but you're giving it the *address* of your `HDC`.

`Cannot convert from X** to X*` and `Cannot convert from X* to X**` are two of the canonical error messages you will hopefully be able to spot immediately at some point in your life :-) It's almost *always* the same problem (too many, or too few, levels of indirection).